# Нужно разное расстояние между словами в flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image]

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста, в макете между словами используется разное расстояние, но у меня получается сделать только равное. Как можно сделать для каждого слова свой отступ?

```css
.header_list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.header_item {
  margin-right: 82px;
}

.header_link {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #282828;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="header_list">
  <li class="header_item">
    <a href="#!" class="header_link">Преимущества</a>
  </li>
  <li class="header_item">
    <a href="#!" class="header_link">Стоимость</a>
  </li>
  <li class="header_item">
    <a href="#!" class="header_link">Программы</a>
  </li>
  <li class="header_item">
    <a href="#!" class="header_link">Отзывы</a>
  </li>
  <li class="header_item">
    <a href="#!" class="header_link">Контакты</a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я бы на вешем месте не заморачивался с этим. Дизайнеры часто в своей работе не беспокоятся о повторяемости блоков или переменчивом контенте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно использовать псевдокласс :nth-child , что бы обращаться к каждому из элементов по отдельности.
либо задать каждому элемента списка свой класс и для него задать параметры

Comment: Добро пожаловать! Оставьте более развернутый ответ с возможностью воспроизвести предложенное вами решение.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, думал есть способ как то избежать создания нескольких классов)